# Is there anyway I can get my house carl, Lydia back?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've looked everywhere, the breezehome and dragonsreach. In the breezehome it says the bed for Lydia is still owned.
In an earlier quest Lydia got killed by a powerful mage, which I killed by a sneak attack. I've went back multiple times but she still lays there dead. I now have a follower Jenassa, and it said I don't have anyone. 
So is she dead completely and won't be coming back. Or is there a way to bring her back?

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing on PC, you can input the following commands to bring her back

`prid a2c94`

`enable`

`resurrect`

`moveto player`

If you're not playing on PC, then your only option is to reload to an earlier save.

Comment: It should be noted that if she does stay dead, her belongings will show up with her coffin in the Hall of the Dead three days later.